# warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] removed when declaring method inline

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings

With this code

```
enum EnumTypes
{
    one,
    two
};

int enum_to_int(EnumTypes enum_type)
{
    switch(enum_type)
    {
        case one: return 1;
        case two: return 2;
    }
}
```

I get the following warning:

> : In function 'int enum_to_int(EnumTypes)':
> :14:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
>   14 | }

, which I understand is a valid warning since enum_type could have some other value stored than `one` and `two`.

However, if I mark the method as `inline` as the following, the warning disappears.

```
enum EnumTypes
{
    one,
    two
};

inline int enum_to_int(EnumTypes enum_type)
{
    switch(enum_type)
    {
        case one: return 1;
        case two: return 2;
    }
}
```

Should there not be a warning if function is marked inline?

- Link without inline: https://godbolt.org/z/jcscchEGh
- Link with inline: https://godbolt.org/z/6qfeWeYsd

Comment: At the end of the routine, add `throw std::runtime_error("enum_to_int: this can never happen");` to help ensure it never happens.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not searching for a solution. I am more curious as to why the warning is gone and if the initial warning actually has been mitigated. (and we don't use exceptions in our production code)

Comment: My guess is that since `inline` signals the compiler to replace the function call with the body of the function, there is no "end of function"

Comment: It appears GCC `-Wreturn-type` is over-exuberant in that it does not notice that the switch-case is exhaustive for the enumdefs.  I believe as per the C++ standard, the compiler is not required to detect this situation.  GCC has a potentially false positive.

Comment: *and we don't use exceptions in our production code*. Fair enough, a `std::terminate();` is another alternative for a never happen situation.

Comment: Is it really exhaustive? Someone could call `enum_to_int(EnumTypes(2));`. From what I've understood, enum can take values not defined for them (as long as it is in range). See https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#8 and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum for example.

Comment: `enum E { first = 0, second = 1000}; enum_to_int(555);` is valid, too.

Comment: `why the warning is gone` so you want reference to gcc source code? Warning is gone because gcc chooses to, there is no other answer, you can now only inspect why gcc is choosing that. The warning is here https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/gcc/tree-cfg.c , now we can inspect what `inline` changes. `Should there not be a warning if function is marked inline?` There should be, I think you could post it as a bug.

Comment: @KamilCuk I was thinking that maybe there could be some C++ - reasoning because of "inline" that I did not know about. If it's just because of gcc internals then yeah, you're right there is no answer and it's just a bug report.

Comment: Genjutsu's example is valid (valid range is `0b0` (0) to `0b11'1111'1111` (1023)), but `enum_to_int(EnumTypes(2));` is UB because the value is outside the bit range of `0b0` to `0b1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to a non-inline function with external linkage, an inline function or a function with internal linkage (`static`) is guaranteed to be defined in every translation unit (odr-)using the function (or else the program is ill-formed).

The compiler is therefore just being "lazy" and doesn't emit a definition for the inline function, since you don't (odr-)use it in the translation unit.

If you (odr-)use it in any way, it will be emitted and the checks wont be skipped. It is enough to take a pointer to the function:

```
auto ptr = &enum_to_int;
```

And then the warning will appear again.

---

It is probably reasonable that the compiler doesn't check the function for such issues in a translation unit where the definition doesn't need to be emitted. It is guaranteed that the program either doesn't use the function at all, in which case the problem doesn't really matter, or it is (odr-)used in another translation unit and the warning will be produced there.

Checking it in all translation units would probably just be wasted time.

Comment: Oh right, the compiler can instantiate the method lazily now that it is inline. It seems that a normal function call also triggers that warning (not sure why I didn't check that). Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

`inline` does not guarantee that the function is inlined. It might be inlined or not. I did not manage to call the function and not get the warning. For example:

```
enum EnumTypes
{
    one,
    two
};

inline int enum_to_int(EnumTypes enum_type)
{
    switch(enum_type)
    {
        case EnumTypes::one: return 1;
        case EnumTypes::two: return 2;
    }
}

int main() {
    return enum_to_int(1);
}
```

Results in:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:17:24: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'EnumTypes' [-fpermissive]
   17 |     return enum_to_int(1);
      |                        ^
      |                        |
      |                        int
<source>:7:34: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int enum_to_int(EnumTypes)'
    7 | inline int enum_to_int(EnumTypes enum_type)
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
<source>: In function 'int enum_to_int(EnumTypes)':
<source>:14:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   14 | }
      | ^
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:17:24: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'EnumTypes' [-fpermissive]
   17 |     return enum_to_int(1);
      |                        ^
      |                        |
      |                        int
<source>:7:34: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int enum_to_int(EnumTypes)'
    7 | inline int enum_to_int(EnumTypes enum_type)
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
<source>: In function 'int enum_to_int(EnumTypes)':
<source>:14:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   14 | }
      | ^
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

UB is only triggered when the function is actually called. And there is no UB when `0` or `1` is passed. It might be intentional, that there is no return otherwise.

However, I would expect the warning nevertheless. It can be considered a bug.